# Need to Extract The price And name of a product in a ArrayList

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist

I have a problem when I want to extract the price of a product included in an ArrayList in c#.

```
    namespace Proyecto_Nahuel
{
    class Program
    {

        ArrayList producto = new ArrayList();
        int numero = 5;
        int numero_precio = 5;
        int precio;
        public void productos()
        {

            foreach (string str in producto)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(str);
            }
        }
        public void inicio()
        {
            producto.Add("|Categoria |" + " Producto | " + " Precio\n");
            producto.Add("1- |Golosina |" + " Chupetin | " + 50 + "\n");
            producto.Add("2- |Bebida |" + " Coca Cola | " + 30 + "\n");
            producto.Add("3- |Snack's |" + " Doritos | " + 45 + "\n");
            producto.Add("4- |Galletas |" + " Chocolina | " + 39 + "\n");
        }
        public void Agregar_Producto()
        {
            
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la categoria del producto a agregar(Golosina / Bebida / Snack's / Galletas");
            string Categoria_Nueva = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Nombre del producto: ");
            string Producto_Nuevo = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Precio del Nuevo Producto: ");
            int Precio_Nuevo = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            producto.Add($"{numero}- |{Categoria_Nueva} |" + $" {Producto_Nuevo} | " + $"{Precio_Nuevo}\n");
            numero += 1;

        }
        public void Comprar_Productos()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            foreach (string str in producto)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(str);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese El numero del Producto que desea comprar");
            int Numero_producto = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Producto Elegido: " + producto[(Numero_producto)]);
            Console.WriteLine("Cuantas unidades Desea?");
            int unidades = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        }
```

you can see that the value that the user enters for the new product to be stored in the list is stored in the Precio_New variable.
What I need, is that when calling the method Comprar_Products, I should be able to save in a variable the price of the product that the customer has chosen at that time, to later be able to calculate the price to pay! Thank you

Comment: Please note the blue box in the [`ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netcore-3.1) documentation, which states: *"We don't recommend that you use the `ArrayList` class for new development. Instead, we recommend that you use the generic `List<T>` class."*

Comment: I would opt for a `Product` class instead of a string. That would make it a bit more straight forward and easier to deal with.

Comment: ...one of the many, many reasons it is important to check the documentation once in a while, especially when you are starting out. The illusion of knowledge is a dangerous thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I suggest to use a list of objects? It will be cleaner and easier to go through with code.

Here is your product:

```
public class Producto 
{
    public int Numero { get; set; }
    public string Categoria { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public int Precio { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your code, you can create a [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netcore-3.1) of products and add to them later on.

```
var productos = new List<Producto>()
{
    new Producto(){ Numero = 1, Categoria = "Golosina", Nombre = "Chupetin", Precio = 50 },
    new Producto(){ Numero = 2, Categoria = "Bebida", Nombre = "Coca Cola", Precio = 30 }
};

productos.Add(new Producto(){ Numero = 3, Categoria = "Snack's", Nombre = "Doritos ", Precio = 45});
```

If you want to display like above, use this code. The $ sign is [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated):

```
  foreach(var producto in productos)
      Console.WriteLine($"{producto.Numero} - {producto.Categoria} | {producto.Nombre} | {producto.Precio}");
```

If you want to search through the list for a given product, just use linq extentions ([Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netcore-3.1), [SingleOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault?view=netcore-3.1)):

```
    var seleccion = "Chupetin";
    var productoSeleccionado = productos.Where(p => p.Nombre == seleccion).SingleOrDefault();
    var seleccionPrecio = productoSeleccionado.Precio;
```

I will leave it up to you to combine these codes with how you want your application to work. I also have links on this answer to direct you to the official C# documentation. It will be overwhelming at first, but with lots of practice and failing you will be able to code your application with ease.